# Search for lines with specific text in files and output file names (file command and grep)

Tags: regex, linux, shell, grep, find

I know this question may be simple to some of you, but I have tried several combinations and googled a lot, without success.

Problem: I have a bunch of files with a given file name, but in different directories.

For example, I have a file called 'THEFILE.txt' in directories a, b, c, d. I am in a directory that has these as subdirectories. In each of 'THEFILE.txts' I am looking for lines with the following pattern :'Has this property blah blah blah _apple'. So what I know for sure about the line is that it starts with 'Has this property ' and ends with '_apple'.

I tried:

1. find . -name 'THEFILE.txt' -exec grep -l 'Has this property' {} \;
   This works, but I get each and every line with 'Has this property'. I only want ones with _apple at the end
2. So I tried:
   find . -name 'THEFILE.txt' -exec grep -l 'Has this property*_apple' {} \; //Does not work, and from my google searches, I don't expect it to.
3. So, next I tried:
   find . -name 'THEFILE.txt' -exec grep -l 'Has this property[!-~]*_apple' {} \;
   //DOES NOT WORK
4. find . -name 'THEFILE.txt' -exec grep 'Has this property' {} \; | grep '_apple$' 
   //This outputs all matching lines, but not the file names
5. find . -name 'THEFILE.txt' -exec grep 'Has this property' {} \; | grep -l '_apple$'
   //Says file is stdin

Expected output: (say files a and c have desired lines)

```
./a/THEFILE.txt
./c/THEFILE.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use grep -r, and pipe it into awk if you only want the filenames.

`grep -r "_apple$" . | awk -F: '{print $1}'`

Comment: Hi Toni, Thanks for the reply, but I need lines with "Has this property" at the beginning AND "_apple" at end. Your soln only matches 1 condn, I already know how to do that

Comment: So just update the regular expression to match what you want: `grep -r "^Has this property.*_apple$" . | awk -F: '{print $1}'`

Comment: Thanks, that totally solved my problem. I really need to learn to use regex better.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt 2. was almost there. With a little adjustment:

```
find . -name THEFILE.txt -exec grep -q '^Has this property.*_apple$' '{}' ';' -print
```

it is more precise than recursive grepping and simpler (no pipeline).

The reason why the above works (as opposed to `grep -l`), is that the `-exec` action evaluates to whatever the exit status of its command was.
`grep` will exit with 0 status (which is `true`) if it finds what it looked for, that will make `-exec` yield `true`, and that in turn will cause the next action (`-print`) to be taken too.